# Rails 4 Query String Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

So i have this query string

```
<a href="/reports/user?q=<%= current_user.id %>">
# => /reports/user?q=1
```

was working fine in rails 3 but throws

```
Couldn't find Report with id=user
```

with rails 4.

```
#routes.rb
get "reports/:field" => "reports#search"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You route here

```
get "reports/:field" => "reports#search"
```

will call `search` method with `params = {field:"user"}`

if you want it to work with same url then change the route to :

```
get "reports/user" => "reports#search"
```

and in `search` use `q` instead of `field`

**OR**

change the link to

```
<a href="/reports/<%= current_user.id %>">
```

Comment: We need to keep the url the same, the first suggestion worked!